# PullToRefresh always have shadow at the top and bottom of listview.How to hide it?

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I add PullToRefresh(https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) Listview in my app.

Then scroll it to the bottom or top ,it auto show the shadow.
[image]

And i set some attribute in xml like

```
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/pull_refresh_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#19000000"
    android:dividerHeight="4dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
```

It could not hide it.

Any one could help me??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is the divider I think, remove

```
android:divider="#19000000"
android:dividerHeight="4dp"
```

and it should work now